# Closing database connection In Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, database, postgresql, database-connection, laravel-5.1

Is that possible to close the database connection after running each database query in Laravel 5.1. I have already built an application by using the Laravel 5.1 and PostgreSQL, and in my server there are limited number of connections has been provided to connect with the database, that's why sometimes I am getting the error "To Many Connections". So please tell me how I can resolve this problem.

I am not sure if Laravel automatically closes the db connection after each db request.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `DB::disconnect('foo');`
But keep in mind Laravel closes connection to DB automatically at the end of the script.
So your problem is somewhere else.

Workaounrd here would be unlimit connection from `localhost` or for particular `user`. Because each visitor of your website opens a new connection to DB