# When does Laravel close connections to the database after performing a select query?

Tags: php, database, laravel, connection

I'm fairly new to Laravel (working with 5.8) so please bear with me if I'm asking from a mis-informed position, but I was unable to find the specifics of this in the Laravel docs. When I query the database:

```
public function getProcessedData(): \Illuminate\Support\Collection
{
    $results = DB::connection("db_name")->select("SELECT * FROM table");
    ... further row by row processing of $results
}
```

When does the above connection close if its included in a function that further processes the data? As I understand it, Laravel returns the resultset as an array of stdClass objects, so I assume it closes the connection after it stores the objects in the array. Does it close as soon as the resultset is stored in the array, or at the end of this particular function? Appreciate any help/clarification in advance!

To clarify this question since Froxz answered a similar question:
What constitutes the script in this case? Is it the function in which the connection is made? Or Laravel's internal API controlling the creation of the connection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closing database connection In Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257347/closing-database-connection-in-laravel-5-1)

Comment: Hi Giacomo, thanks for the link! I saw that question and its corresponding answer, and I guess my question is asking to clarify what constitues the script here? The function in which the connection method is being called? Or is it the script that runs internally via Laravel's API?

Comment: the script is the loading of page entirely